# Cannot assign valid constant(value) to a Generic Type variable

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following not work?

```java
void execute() {
 Integer a = Integer.valueOf(1);

 a = reassign(a);

 D.log("a: " + a);
}

<T extends Integer> T reassign(T t) {
  t = Integer.valueOf(2); // error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to T
  // t = (T) Integer.valueOf(2); // This works but with  warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
  return t;
}

<T extends Integer> T reassign2(T t, T anotherT) {
  t = anotherT; // This works without any warning.
  return t;
}
```

My understanding is that generic methods/classes/interfaces will be compiled to a single class file where the type parameter is replaced with most appropriate lower bound (Integer in the above case).

Java env: java 11.0.4 2019-07-16 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that generic methods/classes/interfaces will be compiled to a single class file where the type parameter is replaced with most appropriate lower bound

Your understanding is correct, but compilers are designed to handle generics more intelligently. If compilers are designed exactly the way you described, what's the point of generics? I could just write a method taking an `Integer` instead. There's no need for generics, since the compiler will *just* replace whatever type parameter I have with `Integer` anyway.

You have specified that `T` must be `Integer` or a subclass of `Integer`. Think about the situation when `T` is a subclass of `Integer`, would the following assignment still work? It wouldn't!

```
t = Integer.valueOf(2); // you are assigning an instance of a superclass to a subclass variable
```

You could argue that `Integer` cannot have any subclasses as it is `final`, but the compiler is not designed to check for the `final`ness of classes in this situation. Using `Integer` as a bound here probably means that `reassign` shouldn't be generic at all.

---

Another thing that the compiler do is to insert casts where necessary, but that's not really relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't work is because the compiler can't prove that `T` is actually and not a subtype of `T`. Integer is a bad example here because it is final and no one can extend it but the compile is not smart enough to know that and reason about it.

Imagine you have the following

```
 class Foo{
 }

 class Bar extends Foo {
 }
```

and you call reassign like this

```
reassign(new Bar());
```

Where reassign was allowed to do

```
<T extends Foo> T reassign(T t){
    t = new Foo();
    return t;
}
```

then this would be equivalent of saying

```
Bar b = new Foo()
```

Which is not valid of course

Comment: Thank you, great concise explanation. I accepted the other answer as it was submitted first. Upvoted.